# Rewrite Condition for Query string URL in .htaccess file

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I don't have a good knowledge in .htaccess file, 
Anyhow somewhere I found the code as shown below :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
</IfModule>
```

I am posting the form values to pagedata.php from index.php page as shown below :

```
<!-- index.php page -->
<form name="testform" id="testform" method="post" action="pagedata">
<input type="text" name="firstname">
<input type="text" name="age">
<input type="text" name="city">
</form>
```

Then data is dispalying fine ... But now I need to change the post method to get method.

If I submit the form with get method, then URL is as follows,
http://example.com/pagedata.php?firstname=test&age=26&city=somecity

But I need to convert the above URL as follows,
http://example.com/pagedata/test/26/somecity

How to do this..? Please suggest.

Comment: you should adopt some PHP framework which support routes instead of doing so using `.htaccess` file

Answer (score 0):

Have an additional rule:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+(pagedata)\.php\?firstname=([^&]*)&age=([^&]*)&city=([^\s&]*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1/%2/%3/%4? [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^(pagedata)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?$ /$1.php?firstname=$2&age=$3&city=$4 [QSA,NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ /$1.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

#### Recommended Read: [Apache mod_rewrite Introduction](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/intro.html)

Comment: Hi anubhava, I used above code in .htaccess file and I changed the form method and index.php looks as follows
<form name="testform" id="testform" method="get" action="pagedata.php">
// ...
But still not working is redirecting to http://example.com/pagedata.php?firstname=test&age=26&city=somecity

Comment: You need to use `method="get"` in your form.

Comment: Ok what URL do you see in your browser after form submit?

Comment: I tested again and it worked so some questions on your setup. Q1. Is this the only .htaccess or do you have another? Q2. Is this the only code in this .htaccess? If you have some other code then please post it in question? Q3. What is location of above .htaccess?

Answer (score 0):

Create human-friendly URLs using mod_rewrite

this can help you convert, for example, www.site.ru/product.php?id=123 in www.site.ru/product/123 the following way:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^product/([^/\.]+)/?$ product.php?id=$1 [L]
```